# Sequence as primary key

Tags: sql, oracle11g

is right to use sequence column as primary key?

Comment: THere is no "right" or "wrong." Depends on your table definition, etc.  But, certainly, you can use a sequence's value for a PK.  This is done all the time.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG52700) for example.

Comment: If there is no other candidate key then it should be fine otherwise it violates 3rd normal form "A non prime attribute should not identify another non prime attribute" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very a commom used.
A PK only can be used on a column that do not repeat, and a sequence should attend this requirement.

Comment: I have a coworker who says the sequence can give trouble in the future and a user can delete it from the system. Is this right too?

Comment: ya if they are limited.

Answer (score 0):

It's a new feature in 12c, and it exists in other databases. To be exact, the fact it is a predefined type.